# Exercise 5.8 from Lie Group, Daniel Bump

Tags: differential-geometry, representation-theory, lie-groups, quaternions

In the exercise 5.8 Bump has asked to prove that the group $Sp(4)$ over complex numbers, which is usual complex embedding $U(4)\cap Sp(4,\mathbb{C})$, can be described by,
$$\left\{\begin{pmatrix}
a&b\\-\bar{b}&\bar{a}
\end{pmatrix}: a,b\in\mathbb{H},|a|^2+|b|^2=1\right\}.$$
But how can that be true while we know that $Sp(4)\cong SO(5)$ is a $10$ dimensional group over $\mathbb{R}$ and the above is $7$ dimensional?

If the above is not true, how can we paramatrize $Sp(4)$?

Answer (score 0):

I do not think $Sp_{4}(\mathbb{R})$ and $SO_{5}(\mathbb{R})$ are isomorphic. In particular I think their root systems are different by checking the classification diagram. Another way to see it is the fundamental group for $SO_{5}(\mathbb{R})$ is $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$, while for $Sp_{4}(\mathbb{R})$ it is trivial.

For your question, I think David Bump wanted to show that it is equivalent to quaterionic matrices which preserve the inner product. This force its determinant to be 1 and $AA^{T}=I$. Therefore if we let the matrix to be
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
a&b\\
c&d\\
\end{pmatrix},a,b,c,d\in \mathbb{H}
$$ 
We would have $|a|^{2}+|b|^{2}=1, |c|^{2}+|d|^{2}=1, ad-bc=1$. Together we get $1+1+4=6$ equations as the last one projects into coordinates. Assuming non-degenercy we get dimension $10=16-6$ as desired. But I do not know how to reduce this to David Bump's formula above, or if there is a nice form in general.

Comment: I meant $Sp(4)$ over complex numbers which is also called $Sp^*(2,\mathbb{H})$ and that is isomorphic to $SO(5)$ (a sporadic isogeny).

Comment: Yes, but I do not think it is isomorphic to $SO(5)$. You can also look up the classification table if you wish.

Comment: Please look at Prof. Garrett's note: http://www-users.math.umn.edu/~garrett/m/v/sporadic_isogenies.pdf
 The list of sporadic isogenies in page 1.

Comment: @Kunnysan: He probably meant a covering map of some kind, not an isomorphism. For the classification table see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_simple_Lie_groups. The end has the list of simple Lie groups of small dimension.